# Browser is making an HTTP call after reloading an angular webpage

Tags: django, angular, http, https

Hello I’m working on an angular project and I’ve few APIs to call.. I’ve set up the API Url as

`const SERVER_URL = https://api.example.com`

And it’s working perfectly fine unless and until I reload the page after some successful API Calls and then make an API call again..

I’m getting CORS error that:

`[blocked] The page at https://staging.example.com was not allowed to display insecure content from http://api.example.com`

Do anyone know where I’m doing things wrong? Because I’ve few other projects and I use same coding practices in them as well but they are working perfectly fine..

PS: Backend is in Django

Comment: please add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` in  header part of index.html, for more refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are getting data from the insecure API.(HTTP)